# Jenkins and Jmetere in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jmeter

I'm new to the docker world. I'm trying to run the JMeter script via Jenkins. I did successfully on local machine but now I want to do same thing in the docker. The commands that I have used on the local machine:

> jmeter -n -t sample-test/sample-test.jmx -l results/test.csv  -e -o
>   results/test.html

I created a docker-compose.yml file  which looks like

```
version: '3.3'
    services:
        jmeter_master:
            container_name: jmeter_master
            build: 
              context: ./jmeter_master
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
            tty: true
            hostname: master
            networks:
              - vins
            volumes:
                - ./sample_test:/results
        jmeter_slave01:
            container_name: jmeter_slave01
            build: 
              context: ./jmeter_slave
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
            tty: true
            hostname: master
            networks:
              - vins
    networks:
        vins:
           driver: bridge
```

The idea here is to do "distributed testing" with JMeter slaves. I ran this for testing purposes and got the expected result (HTML report). The commands that I have used:

```
docker-compose up
docker exec -it jmeter_master /bin/bash
jmeter -n -t sample-test/sample-test.jmx -l sample-test/test.csv  -e -o sample-test/test.html  -R172.21.0.3,172.21.0.4
```

Now I don't know how to continue work. I want to run JMeter command inside Jenkins that should be also in docker container but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Should I add one more Jenkins service in docker-compose.yml? How to access other containers and run commands or I'm on the wrong way? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

So far I don't see any connectivity between Jenkins and JMeter (unless you specified something in the [Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/))

If you want to orchestrate JMeter builds using Jenkins you need to:

1. Create a job which will kick off JMeter tests, see [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) for details
2. Add Jenkins container as a [build agent](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Havemasterlaunchagentviassh)
3. You can kick off jobs and get basic results using [Jenkins Remote Access API](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217911388-Best-Practice-For-Using-Jenkins-REST-API)
4. If you need advanced reporting take a look at [Jenkins Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html)